# About ADSL modem disconnection with the port error report

Tags: wireless-networking, modem

I am seeing my profile in my Intent ISP site and there are many disconnections by the `port error` as you can see below:

[image: port errors]

my modem is [ADSL tp-link](https://www.tp-link.com/au/home-networking/dsl-modem-router/td-w9960/) as you can see below:

[image: modem rounter]

If possible I like to know why this error is happening, does it come from my modem or its is from the ISP.

Comment: Ask your ISP...

Comment: This seems extremely likely to be an issue outside your control - ie the port the DSL modem is connecting to at the exchange/cabinet/equivalent.   As @DavidPostill said, you need to raise this with your ISP.

Comment: I have asked for the ISP, and they said it is because  the contention with tor modem is disconnected and don't know the problem is from our side or your side, but I have changed the modem and I guess it will show that this is from my side or not.

Comment: Has your ISP provisioned you an ADSL or VDSL connection?   If they have provisioned a VDSL connection, that could be your problem.

Comment: They have Provided the ADSL connection.